# Running Void glibc as guest on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, void-linux

I installed from `void-live-x86_64-20210218-xfce.iso` into latest Virtualbox on macOS Big Sur. After installation I installed `xbps-install -Sv virtualbox-ose-guest`  Virtual Box Guest Additions and did a reboot.

I now get the error:

```
VBoxClient: Failed to get display change request, rc=VERR_INVALID_HANDLE
VBoxClient: Failure waiting for event, rc=VERR_INVALID_HANDLE
```

Screenshot:

[image]

How to run Void Linux glibc in Virtualbox?

Answer (score 0):

Install on Void Linux this two packages:

xbps-install -Syu virtualbox-ose-guest virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms

reboot

Devices/Optical Drives add VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
on Windows 10 for example in dir - C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
[image]
reboot
On Xfce Desktop - VBox_GAs_6.1.32 (or your version)
click on Icon(automount)

run terminal
got to
cd /run/media/{username}/VBox_GAs_6.1.32
cd /run/media/$USER/VBox_GAs_6.1.32

run VBoxLinuxAdittions.run

sudo reboot
Ctrl-F
In general, as usual, as in other Linux distributions